# Dimming / Transforming current app screen

Tags: ios, modal-dialog, transition, user-experience, interaction

How do you achieve animating dimming / transforming the current app screen and then displaying another modal or view on top? Does this involve taking a screenshot of the current screen then using a custom transition or is there another method of achieving this? If so, can you provide sample code?

It may be easier to show a screenshot of other apps achieving this interaction (screens from Uber, Tweetbot 3.0, and Tumblr apps):

[image: Uber]

[TweetBot 3.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjISW.png)

[Tumblr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcinX.jpg)

[Tumblr #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8m9o.png)

Answer (score 3):

What I've done is to put a window-sized UIView on top of the current view controller's content view, with the opaque property set to NO and a background color of back with an opacity of 50%. Then I put a view on top of that. Works well.

You need to add logic to the current view controller to set up and manage it. Make the dark overlay view an outlet and put the other display view in it as a subview. That way you can simply remove the overlay view from the view controller's content view to make it go away. You might also want some sort of animation, in which case you might want separate outlets for the overlay view and the content view that you're displaying on top of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom animated transition in iOS 7 to do this.

If you set the modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom on the toVC (modal) it will keep the fromVC (background) around after the transition. You can also change the alpha of the fromVC as part of the transition to dim the background.

Check out my implementation of the sample code for WWDC Session 218: Custom Transitions Using View Controllers. If you click on Options you'll get a modal transition with a background dim similar to what you're looking for.

https://github.com/soleares/SOLPresentingFun